# Can't do async in redux action

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-router, redux-thunk

i already use redux thunk to do async. it already work with this format :

```
export function registerUser({email,password}){
    return function(dispatch){
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/api/auth/signup`,{email,password})
            .then(response =>{
                dispatch({type:AUTH_USER});
                localStorage.setItem('laravel_user_token',response.data.token);
                browserHistory.push('/register');
            })
            .catch(response => dispatch(authError(response.data.error)));
    }
}
```

now i want to try do some async in logout action like this :

```
export function logoutUser() {
    console.log("logout");
    localStorage.removeItem('laravel_user_token');
    return { type: LOGOUT_USER }
}
```

that's work, Now i intend to redirect the page after logout was performed with this code:

```
export function logoutUser() {
    return dispatch => {
        console.log("logout");
        localStorage.removeItem('laravel_user_token');
        return dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_USER })
        .then(() => 
            browserHistory.push("/")
        );
    }
}
```

My problem is no responses comeback, even my console.log("logout") is not work.

Comment: `return dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_USER })
        .then(() => 
            browserHistory.push("/")
        );` this won't work since dispatch doesn't return promise here, so `.then` doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some variants how you can perform it.

### **1. Via promises**

This, way as you tried, is performing using `Promise`, so your *main* error - **that your function is not returning** `Promise`.

Change your action

```
export function logOut() {
 return (dispatch) =>  {
  return new Promise((resolve) => { 
      dispatch({
         type    : LOGOUT_USER,
      });

      resolve();
  }
}
```

Your action handler can be simple reducer function, that will change the state.

```
case 'LOGOUT_USER' : (state) =>  {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    autenticated : false
  })
}
```

And then, call it from the react component.

```
hireLogoutClick = () => {
   this.props.logOut().then(() => browserHistory.push('/');
}
```

`logOut` function return [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which will call your callback function on `resolve()` step. Firstly will be called your reducer function and then will be called your callback (function passed in `.then`)

---

### **2. Via middleware**

There is another variant, how to perform this, via middleware, and call it from reducer, like an action, middleware will catch it and redirect, for my opinion better, then use promises.

Create a middleware

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { ROUTING } from '../constants/ActionTypes'

 export const redirect = store => next => action => {  
    if(action){
       if (action.type === ROUTING) {
         browserHistory['push'](action.nextUrl)
     }
  }

   return next(action)
 }
```

Bind it

```
// Apply the middleware to the store
const middleware = routerMiddleware(browserHistory)
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
)
```

Use :)

```
export function logOut () {
    return (dispatch) =>  {
      dispatch({
         type    : types.LOGOUT_USER
      })

      dispatch({
         type : types.ROUTING,
         nextUrl: '/'
     })
   }
  }
```

Comment: how could i add `objectAssign({}, state, {authenticated: false});` in my reducer then?. i try this code : `case 'LOGOUT_USER' : (state) => {
            objectAssign({}, state, {authenticated: false});
            return dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_USER }).then(() => 
                browserHistory.push("/")
            );
        }`  .can you help me fix the code  @Dmitriy Kovalenko

Comment: Updated, to include exmaple of changing state

Comment: in where i put `return dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_USER }).then(() => 
    browserHistory.push("/")
);` because in reducer already return `objectAssign({}, state, {authenticated: true});`  @Dmitriy Kovalenko

Comment: You call the action => `logoutUser`, it return the `Promise`, and call your reducer, which update your state, after that, action resolving the promise, and call the callback

Comment: You call dispatch(logOut()), from your react component

Comment: am i need to create another case in reducer for that?. sorry if i'm asking to much. i still new in this one. @Dmitriy Kovalenko

Comment: No, call it from the component in react, or if you use `mapDispatchToProps `, pass it as props, and use it from props

Comment: hmmm. could you update your code above to give me the example. i don't know where after resolving a promise i have to call the callback?. i already pass logoutUser action through mapDispatchToProps  @Dmitriy Kovalenko

Comment: `const Logged = (props) => {

  const doLogout = () => {
    props.logout().then(() => browserHistory.push('/'));
  }`  i got this error : `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: dispatch is not defined` in my action. @Dmitriy Kovalenko

Comment: In your example, you already use dispatch, in logOut function, check that you have bind thunk-middleware

Comment: i already bind thunk middleware. on my example. i pass the `dispatch` as a parameter in the function. could i do it just like this: `return new Promise((resolve, dispatch) => {`  ? @Dmitriy Kovalenko

Comment: As in answer:
`return (dispatch) =>  {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {`

Comment: i got another error too `Uncaught TypeError: props.logout(...).then is not a function` @Dmitriy Kovalenko.

Comment: i'm trying use this `export function logoutUser(){
    return (dispatch) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => { 
            dispatch({
                type    : LOGOUT_USER,
            }).then(()=>resolve())
        })
    }
};`  but it still get the same error